# Hash Function Calculation

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, hash

I need a hash function that maps the values 0-9 to 0, 10-19 to 1, 20-29 to 2, 30-39 to 3, and -1 to -9 to -1, -10 to -19 to -2, etc

```
int hash (int value) {
    return (int)(value / 10);
}
```

works for positive numbers, but 0 to -9 maps to 0 and negative numbers are wrong. What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: How can `0` be mapped to **both** `1` and `-1`?

Comment: fixed. The negative numbers should give a negative hash, i was just including decimal values as well (-0.00000001), but really this function takes an integer so that should not matter

Comment: Why does this have the Java tag?

Comment: The boundaries are skewed now. They should be `-1 to -10`, `-11 to -20` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it's not that hard, is it.

```
int val = value / 10;
if(value < 0)
    val--;
return val;
```

Comment: `return ( value - ( value < 0 ? 1 : 0 )  ) / 10;` could be better, but I doubt anything can make this ugly hashing function better.

Comment: It would be "better" only if you intend to write code that's as hard to read as possible.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a mathematical way instead of using a conditional, but I Guess not.

Comment: This also doesn't work. Take input -4 as value, -4 / 10 will give you 0 when it should give you -1.

Comment: @HansLanda yes, `-4 / 10` will give you `0`, and since `-4` is negative you decrement the return value by one. This is basic math, come on.

Comment: @HansLanda It is possible to write this without a conditional if you do some bit fiddling. Shift highest bit of `value` which indicates the sign to the low bit. Substract this from `value / 10`.

Comment: @kayaman Who needs math when you have calculators? Honestly, get with the times. But no, I just glanced over it and didn't realize you used value instead of val. Perhaps we should use a different variable name for value or val.

Comment: @kayaman This wasn't really designed to be a "Hashing function" for what I wanted it for. I was actually looking for a bit-shfiting approach for assigning specific values to bins. I quickly realized value / binsize does not work for negative values. I also realized I can use a simple conditional, but to me this looks ugly for some reason. Thus, I asked stackoverflow and wanted to see if anyone could come up with an elegant solution using bit shifting or something. I often like leaving questions pretty open so I can see a variety of solutions. Sometimes people end up calling me an idiot though

Comment: I'm less of an "elegant micro solution"-man and more of a "more value for the company through efficient design"-man, and my answers tend to reflect that. It's also hard to assess some questions/askers, when you don't know if their question is correct (XY problem), whether they're idiots, or whether I'm the idiot. SO is a hard game sometimes. You could've elaborated on your question what you're looking for in an answer, since as it is it doesn't really come off as anything except "how to get correct value".